# How do I create a piecewise function using Do[] or While[]?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, piecewise

The following non-linear circuit is an *uncontrolled three-phase full-wave 6-pulse rectifier*. The inputs are $v_{an}(t) = V_m \sin (\omega t)$, $v_{bn}(t) = V_m \sin (\omega t-120°)$ and $v_{cn}(t) = V_m \sin (\omega t+120°)$. $R$ and $L$ are the load's resistance and inductance, $\omega$ and $T$ are the voltage sources' angular frequency and period, and $V_m$ is the sources' amplitude; the diodes are modeled as ideals. The unknown to solve for is the load's current (not shown in the diagram), $i(t)$. The circuit's differential equation is

$i'(t) + \dfrac{R}{L} i(t) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3} V_m}{L} \sin{(\omega t + \theta)} \tag*{}$

subject to the initial condition

$i(t_0) = I_0 \ge 0 \tag*{}$

[image: Uncontrolled three-phase full-wave 6-pulse rectifier]

At any instant in time, only one upper diode and one lower diode conduct (are ON), so two of the three voltage sources are carrying current. During one cycle $T$, each diode conducts for $T/3$ seconds, and each transition occurs every $T/6$ seconds; the diodes turn on in the sequence $D_1$, $D_2$, $D_3$, $D_4$, $D_5$, $D_6$, $D_1$,... Due to the non-linearity, there's not a single expression that describes the solution of the circuit for all $ t \ge 0 $. However, we can obtain a piecewise solution: for each cycle, we divide $i(t)$ in seven segments/pieces, each of which has the same general form, which is the solution to the previous ODE:

$i(t) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3} V_m \omega L}{R^2 + (\omega L)^2} (- \cos{(\omega t + \theta)} + e^{\frac{R}{L}(t_0-t)} \cos{(\omega t_0 + \theta)}) + \dfrac{\sqrt{3} V_m R}{R^2 + (\omega L)^2} (\sin{(\omega t + \theta)} - e^{\frac{R}{L}(t_0-t)} \sin{(\omega t_0 + \theta)}) + I_0 e^{\frac{R}{L}(t_0-t)} \tag*{}$

where the intervals for each of these pieces are the following, with $k=0,1,2,3,...$:

- Interval $kT<t<k T+T/12$: $v_{bn} < v_{an} < v_{cn} \implies$ the diodes $D_5, D_6$ are ON and the rest are OFF; $v_o=v_{cb}$ so $\theta =+90°$.
- Interval $k T+T/12<t<k T+T/4$: $v_{bn} < v_{cn} < v_{an} \implies$ the diodes $D_1, D_6$ are ON and the rest are OFF; $v_o=v_{ab}$ so $\theta =+30°$.
- Interval $k T+T/4<t<k T + 5T/12$: $v_{cn} < v_{bn} < v_{an} \implies$ the diodes $D_1, D_2$ are ON and the rest are OFF; $v_o=v_{ac}$ so $\theta =-30°$.
- Interval $k T+5T/12<t<k T + 7T/12$: $v_{cn} < v_{an} < v_{bn} \implies$ the diodes $D_3, D_2$ are ON and the rest are OFF; $v_o=v_{bc}$ so $\theta =-90°$.
- Interval $k T+7T/12<t<k T + 3T/4$: $v_{an} < v_{cn} < v_{bn} \implies$ the diodes $D_3, D_4$ are ON and the rest are OFF; $v_o=v_{ba}$ so $\theta =-150°$.
- Interval $k T+3T/4<t<k T + 11T/12$: $v_{an} < v_{bn} < v_{cn} \implies$ the diodes $D_5, D_4$ are ON and the rest are OFF; $v_o=v_{ca}$ so $\theta =+150°$.
- Interval $k T+11T/12<t<k T + T$: $v_{bn} < v_{an} < v_{cn} \implies$ the diodes $D_5, D_6$ are ON and the rest are OFF; $v_o=v_{cb}$ so $\theta =+90°$.

**I want to implement the following algorithm in Mathematica**, in order to define `i[t]` as a piecewise function and plot it. Obviously the `Piecewise[]` function will be needed, and perhaps `Do[]` or `While[]`, and `Module[]` might be helpful, but I don't know how to use them to define a piecewise function.

> Given the circuit's parameters `R`, `L`, `w`, `T = 2 Pi/w`,
> `Vm`, the initial condition `IC` at $t=0$, and the number `n` (`n` is a natural number used to end the loop). In the following, whenever I say "`expr`", sustitute it with `(Sqrt[3] Vm w L)/(R^2 + (w L)^2) (- Cos[w t + θ] + E^(R/L (t0 - t)) Cos[w t0 + θ]) + (Sqrt[3] Vm R)/(R^2 + (w L)^2) (Sin[w t + θ] - E^(R/L (t0 - t)) Sin[w t0 + θ]) + I0 E^(R/L (t0 - t))`
>
> 1. Set `k = 0`.
> 2. For `k T < t ≤ k T + T/12`:
>
>    1. Set `θ = 90 Degree`. If `k == 0`, set `t0 = 0`. If `k ≥ 1`, set `t0 = k T`.
>    2. If `k == 0`, set `I0 = IC`. If `k ≥ 1`, set `I0 = i[t0]`.
>    3. Add/append `expr` (using the new values of `t0`, `I0` and `θ`) as a new piece of `i[t]` for the interval `k T < t ≤ k T + T/12`.
> 3. For `k T + T/12 < t ≤ k T + T/4`:
>
>    1. Set `t0 = k T + T/12` and `θ = 30 Degree`.
>    2. Set `I0 = i[t0]`.
>    3. Add `expr` (using the new values of `t0`, `I0` and `θ`) as a new piece of `i[t]` for the interval `k T + T/12 < t ≤ k T + T/4`.
> 4. For `k T + T/4 < t ≤ k T + 5 T/12`:
>
>    1. Set `t0 = k T + T/4` and `θ = -30 Degree`.
>    2. Set `I0 = i[t0]`.
>    3. Add `expr` (using the new values of `t0`, `I0` and `θ`) as a new piece of `i[t]` for the interval `k T + T/4 < t ≤ k T + 5 T/12`.
> 5. For `k T + 5 T/12 < t ≤ k T + 7 T/12`:
>
>    1. Set `t0 = k T + 5 T/12` and `θ = -90 Degree`.
>    2. Set `I0 = i[t0]`.
>    3. Add `expr` (using the new values of `t0`, `I0` and `θ`) as a new piece of `i[t]` for the interval `k T + 5 T/12 < t ≤ k T + 7 T/12`.
> 6. For `k T + 7 T/12 < t ≤ k T + 3 T/4`:
>
>    1. Set `t0 = k T + 7 T/12` and `θ = -150 Degree`.
>    2. Set `I0 = i[t0]`.
>    3. Add `expr` (using the new values of `t0`, `I0` and `θ`) as a new piece of `i[t]` for the interval `k T + 7 T/12 < t ≤ k T + 3 T/4`.
> 7. For `k T + 3 T/4 < t ≤ k T + 11 T/12`:
>
>    1. Set `t0 = k T + 3 T/4` and `θ = 150 Degree`.
>    2. Set `I0 = i[t0]`.
>    3. Add `expr` (using the new values of `t0`, `I0` and `θ`) as a new piece of `i[t]` for the interval `k T + 3 T/4 < t ≤ k T + 11 T/12`.
> 8. For `k T + 11 T/12 < t ≤ k T + T`:
>
>    1. Set `t0 = k T + 11 T/12` and `θ = 90 Degree`.
>    2. Set `I0 = i[t0]`.
>    3. Add `expr` (using the new values of `t0`, `I0` and `θ`) as a new piece of `i[t]` for the interval `k T + 11 T/12 < t ≤ k T + T`.
> 9. Increase `k` by one, that is, evaluate `k++` or set `k = k + 1`.
> 10. If `k < n`, return to step 2 and repeat. If `k == n`, stop the loop/algorithm.

## Edit

I just followed my steps, and managed to do it. I changed step 2 a little. Also, the `Piecewise[]` function in Mathematica is a bit strange, so I changed a bit the other steps (notice for example I had to use `i` instead of `i[t]`, and that I used the `Drop[]` and `First[]` functions). And I also wrote additional code in order to append each new piece of $i(t)$. The code is the following.

```
(*Step 0*)
    Clear[i, t0, I0, θ, t, list, k];
    expr[t0_, I0_, θ_] := (Sqrt[3] Vm w L)/(R^2 + L^2 w^2) ( - Cos[t w + θ] + E^(R/L (t0 - t)) Cos[t0 w + θ]) + (Sqrt[3] Vm R)/(R^2 + L^2 w^2) (Sin[t w + θ] - E^(R/L (t0 - t)) Sin[t0 w + θ]) + I0 E^(R/L (t0 - t));
(*Step 1*)
    k = 0;
While[
        k < n
    ,
        (*Step 2*)
            θ = 90 Degree;
            If[
                    k == 0
                ,
                    t0 = 0;
                    I0 = IC;
                    i = Piecewise[{{N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T < t <= k T + T/12}}]
                ,
                    t0 = k T;
                    I0 = i /. {t -> t0};
                    list = First[Drop[Delete[0] /@ {i}, -1]];(*Get the pieces of i[t], including both the expressions and the intervals*)
                    AppendTo[list, {N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T < t <= k T + T/12}]; (*Append the new piece to i[t]*)
                    i = Piecewise[list] (*Re-define i[t] with the new piece added*)
            ];
        (*Step 3*)
            θ = 30 Degree;
            t0 = k T + T/12;
            I0 = i /. {t -> t0};
            list = First[Drop[Delete[0] /@ {i}, -1]]; (*Get the pieces of i[t], including both the expressions and the intervals*)
            AppendTo[list, {N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T + T/12 < t <= k T + T/4}]; (*Append the new piece to i[t]*)
            i = Piecewise[list]; (*Re-define i[t] with the new piece added*)
        (*Step 4*)
            θ = -30 Degree;
            t0 = k T + T/4;
            I0 = i /. {t -> t0};
            list = First[Drop[Delete[0] /@ {i}, -1]]; (*Same note*)
            AppendTo[list, {N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T + T/4 < t <= k T + 5 T/12}]; (*Same note*)
            i = Piecewise[list]; (*Same note*)
        (*Step 5*)
            θ = -90 Degree;
            t0 = k T + 5 T/12;
            I0 = i /. {t -> t0};
            list = First[Drop[Delete[0] /@ {i}, -1]];
            AppendTo[list, {N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T + 5 T/12 < t <= k T + 7 T/12}];
            i = Piecewise[list];
        (*Step 6*)
            θ = -150 Degree;
            t0 = k T + 7 T/12;
            I0 = i /. {t -> t0};
            list = First[Drop[Delete[0] /@ {i}, -1]];
            AppendTo[list, {N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T + 7 T/12 < t <= k T + 3 T/4}];
            i = Piecewise[list];
        (*Step 7*)
            θ = 150 Degree;
            t0 = k T + 3 T/4;
            I0 = i /. {t -> t0};
            list = First[Drop[Delete[0] /@ {i}, -1]];
            AppendTo[list, {N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T + 3 T/4 < t <= k T + 11 T/12}];
            i = Piecewise[list];
        (*Step 8*)
            θ = 90 Degree;
            t0 = k T + 11 T/12;
            I0 = i /. {t -> t0};
            list = First[Drop[Delete[0] /@ {i}, -1]];
            AppendTo[list, {N[expr[t0, I0, θ]], k T + 11 T/12 < t <= k T + T}];
            i = Piecewise[list];
        (*Step 9*)
            k++
 ]
```

As a test, I chose the same values as the Example 4-12 of Daniel Hart's *Power Electronics* (1st edition): `R = 25; L = 50*10^-3; w = 2*Pi*60; Vm = 480 Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[3]; T = 2 Pi/w; IC = 0; n = 1;`. I got the following curves (the three above are $v_{an}$, $v_{bn}$, $v_{cn}$, the one below is $i$):

[image: Plot of the input voltages and the output current]

The code seems correct. Separately from the previous code, I computed the RMS value of $i(t)$ in steady-state and got a very similar answer to Daniel's. Regardless, **I'm still open to anyone who optimizes the code**.

Comment: Are you after a plot, that is a specific numerical solution versus time, with all parameters having definite numerical values?

Comment: In the differential equation you give, where does Theta come from? Is is an evolving dependent variable like "small i",  or a given function of time,  or a constant?

Comment: Hi Paul. First comment: yes, I'm after a plot, with all parameters having definite numerical values. I already posted the solution for $i(t)$. Second comment: $\theta$ is a constant for each interval (but variable between one interval and the following), that comes from the changing input to the circuit (in order to understand it, I have to explain the circuit a bit). For example, for $kT<t<kT+T/12$ the input is $v_{cn}-v_{bn} = \sqrt{3} V_m \sin{(\omega t+90°)}$, so $\theta=90°$; for $kT+T/12<t<kT+T/4$ the input is $v_{an}-v_{bn} = \sqrt{3} V_m \sin{(\omega t+30°)}$, so $\theta=30°$.

Comment: I created this [circuit in Falstad](http://tinyurl.com/ycuuemxk) so you can visualize it. In the diagram above, the yellow dots are electric charges (so moving dots are electric currents); the green and red colors in wires indicate positive or negative voltage, respectively, with respect to the ground (which I've chosen as the neutral terminal in the three-phase source). In the plot below, the green, red and orange curves are $v_{an}$, $v_{bn}$ and $v_{cn}$, respectively, and the yellow curve is $i$.